# Abrir division en html

Tags: php, html, div

Tengo una tabla con su estilo en css de la siguiente forma:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría poder expandir las divisiones en las que se ve la imagen + añadiendo cierta información debajo.

Para rellenar las celdas uso el siguiente código:

```
echo "<div class='row header'>";
echo "<div class=cell>Defectivos</div>";
echo "<div class=cell>Fecha</div>";
echo "<div class=cell>Orden</div>";
echo "<div class=cell>Fase</div>";
echo "<div class=cell>Puesto</div>";
echo "<div class=cell>Operario</div>";
echo "<div class=cell>Articulo</div>";
echo "<div class=cell>Descripción</div>";
echo "<div class=cell>AutoQ</div>";
echo "</div>";

for ($i = 0; $i < ...; $i++)
{
    echo "<div class=row>";
    if(...)
    {
        echo "<div class=cell data-title=Defectivos><img src=images/expand.png></div>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class=cell data-title=Defectivos></div>";
    }
    echo "<div class=cell data-title=Fecha>FECHA</div>";
    echo "<div class=cell data-title=Orden>PRUEBA</div>";
    echo "<div class=cell data-title=Fase>PRUEBA</div>";
    echo "<div class=cell data-title=Puesto>PRUEBA</div>";
    echo "<div class=cell data-title=Operario>PRUEBA</div>";
    echo "<div class=cell data-title=Articulo>PRUEBA</div>";
    echo "<div class=cell data-title=Descripción>PRUEBA</div>";
    if(...)
    {
        echo "<div class=cell data-title=AutoQ><img src=images/expand.png></div>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<div class=cell data-title=AutoQ></div>"; 
    }
    echo "</div>";
}
```

En las condiciones del if pinto (o no) la imagen + para luego desplegar la información que me falta, pero me gustaria poder mostrar u ocultar otro div pulsando en cada uno de ellos

Ya he añadido el boton y la acción para desplegar con la sugerencia abajo escrito pero ahora cuando se despliega solo es visible el texto Info defectivos en una columna y me gustaría poder hacer mas div dentro en todo el ancho

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora siguiendo las sugerencias tengo este codigo:

```
echo "<div class=row>";
echo "<div class='cell' data-title=AutoQ><div class=mostrarMas><button class=mostrarMas onclick=mostrarOcultar(this)>+</button></div><div class=masInfo style=display:none;></div></div>";
echo "<div class=cell data-title=Fecha>".$resultado[$i]["FECHA"]."</div>";
echo "<div class=cell data-title=Orden>PRUEBA</div>";
echo "<div class=cell data-title=Fase>PRUEBA</div>";
echo "<div class=cell data-title=Puesto>PRUEBA</div>";
echo "<div class=cell data-title=Operario>PRUEBA</div>";
echo "<div class=cell data-title=Articulo>PRUEBA</div>";
echo "<div class=cell data-title=Descripción>PRUEBA</div>";
echo "<div class=cell data-title=AutoQ></div>";
echo "</div>";
echo "<div class=masInfoRow>";
echo "<div class=masInfo>Aqui hay mas info para mostrar</div>";
echo "</div>";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Qué código tienes? ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Te ha fallado algo? ¿Que errores te ha dado? Falta información en la pregunta para poder ayudarte y no hacerte el trabajo entero :)

Comment: Ya he editado la pregunta y añadido código

Comment: `echo "<div class=masInfo>Aquí hay mas info para mostrar</div>";` te falta añadirle un div padre con la clase `row masInfoRow` para que te funcione lo que he hecho, pero la cuestión es entender el código que te he puesto en la respuesta. Léelo bien y compréndelo.

Comment: Ahora si, aunque me sigue apareciendo solo una columna, edito respuesta

Comment: te sugiero revisar esto: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3897808/5215609

Comment: tambien puedes usar herramientas ya existentes como : https://datatables.net/.... para que inventar la rueda del coche..!!

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta, he añadido CSS. Supongo que tu CSS será algo parecido, pero vamos, que solo te queda cambiar los estilos y lo tienes :)

Answer (score 1):

Lo que puedes hacer es crearte otro div oculto debajo del div con la imagen y cuando hagas click en ella lo muestras/ocultas. Esto lo puedes hacer mediante javascript. Te recomiendo añadir la etiqueta javascript a la pregunta también para que la respuesta le pueda servir a mas gente.

La estructura que he usado:

```
<div><!-- container -->
    <div><!-- container img -->
        <img><!-- img -->
    </div>
    <div><!-- container info -->
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Para que ocupe toda la row simplemente vuelve a hacer la comprobación después de que cierras la row y creas el contenedor en una row nueva.

```
echo "</div>";
if(...)
    {
        echo "<div class=row><div class=cell data-title=AutoQ><img src=images/expand.png></div></div>";
    }
```

```js
function mostrarOcultar(ele){
    console.log(ele);
    eleInfo=ele.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
    console.log(eleInfo.nodename);
    if(eleInfo.classList.contains("masInfoRow")){
        if (eleInfo.style.display === "none") {
          eleInfo.style.display = "block";
        } else {
          eleInfo.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.table{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
}

.row{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
}

.cell{
  border : 1px solid black;
  flex:1 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell" data-title="AutoQ">
      <div>
        <button class="mostrarMas" onclick="mostrarOcultar(this)">+</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
    <div class="cell">4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row masInfoRow" style="display:none;">
    <div class="cell">
      <div class="masInfo"  >Aqui hay mas info para mostrar</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: He aplicado lo que tu dices pero al pulsar sobre el boton + ahora me aparece: mas información pero solo ocupa una columna me gustaria que ocupara todo el ancho y poder hacer mas divs dentro, adjunto nueva captura

Comment: Mira la parte del EDIT: de mi respuesta, solo tienes que crear el contenedor con mas info en otra row nueva, para ocultarlo y mostrarlo ahora tendrás que coger el elemento de la siguiente row y hacer una comprobación para ver si es una row de mas info o es una row normal, esto lo puedes hacer añadiendo una clases a la row y comprobándola en el código.,

Comment: No soy capaz de conseguirlo, no estoy usando table, hasta ahora usaba div

Comment: Yo he usado table para no definerme todos los estilos que tienes tu para hacer la row. Actualiza tu codigo para poder verlo y si te sale un error etc...

Comment: Edito mi pregunta para que veas como me queda

Comment: Disculpa hay alguna forma de hablar directamente que no sea por comentarios? no lo consigo de ninguna forma